# $E(|X-Y|)$ for $X$, $Y$ i.i.d and uniform on $[0,1]$

Tags: expected-value, uniform-distribution

What is $E|X-Y|$ when $X$, $Y$ are i.i.d and uniform on $[0,1]$?

I want to do something like

$$
E(|X-Y|)=\iint_{x>y}(x-y)\;dxdy+\iint_{y>x}(y-x)\;dxdy=2\iint_{x>y} (x-y)\;dxdy
$$

But am not sure how to solve that last double integral or if this setup is right.

Comment: The last double integral is just $2\int_0^1 \int_y^1 (x-y)\,dx\,dy=2\int_0^1\left(\int_y^1 x\,dx-y\int_y^1\,dx\right)\,dy$.

Comment: Do you think this setup is right?

Comment: Yes the setup is correct because of symmetry.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: This seems like (most of) an answer; would you mind writing it up so that we can get this question off of the Unanswered queue?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the expectation by symmetry is just

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[|X-Y|]&=\mathbb E[(X-Y)1_{X>Y}]+\mathbb E[(Y-X)1_{Y>X}]
\\&=2\,\mathbb E[(X-Y)1_{X>Y}]
\\&=2\iint (x-y)1_{0<y<x<1}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\\&=2\int_0^1\int_y^1 (x-y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\\&=\frac13
\end{align}