# Calculate $E(|X-Y|)$

Tags: probability

Given that $(X,Y)$ is a random vector with uniform distribution on the unit square $[0,1]^2$ I have to prove that $E(|X-Y|) = \frac{1}{3}$. My work so far is this:
$$g(x, y)=|x-y|=\left\{\begin{array}[rl]
xx-y&if \quad x \geq y \\ y-x & if \quad x <y
\end{array}\right\}$$ 
Therefore I think I can do this:
$$Eg(X, Y)=\iint_{\mathbb{R}}g(x, y)f(x, y) \: dxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^1|x-y|\cdot 1 \: dxdy=$$
$$=\int_0^1\int_0^yy-x\:dxdy+\int_0^1\int_0^xx-y\:dydx=-\frac{1}{3}$$
I think I can separate the integral like this because I have two cases: when $x \geq y$ and when $x<y$. The thing is that I get $E(|X-Y|) = -\frac{1}{3}$ instead of $\frac{1}{3}$ and I don't know where my mistake is. Could someone please help me?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3004029/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^1\int_0^yy-x\:dxdy = \int_0^1\left(y\cdot(y-0)-\int_0^yx\:dx\right)dy=$$
$$=\int_0^1\left(y^2-\frac{1}{2}y^2\right)dy=\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}y^2dy=\left.\frac{1}{6}y^3\right|_{y=0}^1=\frac{1}{6}$$

Now we need to apply this twice to your formula before last = to get a result: $\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an expected value and the support is positive, the final result must be positive. Since you got a negative result, you made a calculation error – but your setup is correct.