# Integrating $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |x-y|\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y$ by hand

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, geometric-probability

Here's a problem from my probability textbook:

> If two points be taken at random on a finite straight line their average distance apart will be one third of the line.

What I did: I got the integral$${{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |x-y|\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y}\over{1^2}},$$which ends up evaluating to ${1\over3}$ according to Wolfram Alpha. However, I am not sure how to evaluate the integral by hand, given that there's the absolute value sign. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Split the integral into two parts, one where $y<x$ and one where $y>x$. Then you can rewrite the integral without the absolute value bars because you'll know the sign of $x-y$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3004029/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $:$ $$\begin{align*}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} |x - y|\ dx\ dy & = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y} (y - x) \ dx\ dy + \int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1} (x - y)\ dx\ dy. \end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks @RabinKumarChakraborty. Can you elaborate in detail how you arrived at the two integrals?

Comment: @Emperor Concerto$:$ I just break the interval in which $x$ varies. First I let $x$ to vary from $0$ to $y$ and then from $y$ to $1.$ Draw pictures to convince yourself.

Comment: Second integral on the right should be $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1} (x - y)\ dx\ dy$

Comment: @Math Lover$:$ That's exactly what I did. Please have a look at it.

Comment: it shows correct now. It showed $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{x} (x - y)\ dx\ dy$ earlier.